# printk params and syslog.h facility names

Tags: linux, module, linux-kernel

There are many params we can pass to printk:

```
 printk (KERN_INFO  "blahahaha");
 printk (KERN_EMERG "bababa");
```

And so forth. Do these tags have anything to do with the facility levels found in syslog.conf? Is KERN_EMERG going to print to facilities specified by "kern.emerg"? How are these two entities tied?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Order of questions:

> Do These Tags have anything to do with the facility levels found in `syslog.conf`?

Yes. The tag is actually a pair, `KERN` `EMERG`, i.e. `KERN` facility, and `EMERG` level - they are in upper-case because it's a preprocessor macro, which is by convention written in upper-case. The Linux kernel only cares about the `KERN` facility, so other facilities are not defined.

What happens is that all of these `printk` commands log to the internal kernel ring buffer. This message may or may not be duplicated to the console (which could be the screen or a serial terminal) based on your kernel settings.

> Is KERN_EMERG going to print to facilities specified by "kern.emerg"?

Assuming that you mean log into files that match `kern.emerg`, then yes. Examples of entries in `syslog.conf` that would match this are `kern.*`, `kern.emerg`, `*.emerg`. A message of the level `emerg` is considered *fatal*, i.e. something seriously bad has happened.

Messages from the kernel at this level may not end up in a syslog file because the error may prevent the writing of data to the hard drive.

> How are these two entities tied?

There is a secondary daemon, typically called `klogd`. It takes the output from the in-kernel ring buffer and by default passes them on to `syslogd` which, records them according to the `syslog.conf` file.

**So in summary**:

`printk` puts the message into the `ring buffer`. The `ring buffer` is read by `klogd` which forwards it to `syslogd`. `Syslogd` records this data into the destination(s) specified by the `syslogd.conf` file.

Comment: Excellent answer - cleared up all my questions. Thanks for this tidbit of knowledge and I'm sure it will help many others in the future.